# Is there a way to search svn commit messages and usernames in jira advanced search when using the jira svn plugin?

Tags: svn, jira

We have the svn plugin for jira installed, and I was wondering if there's any way, using the jira advanced search, to search for parts of the commit message or the user who committed something?

Comment: Just for note. There's a dedicated http://answers.atlassian.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality is part of FishEye, so no.